# Multi line push notification using Ionic 1 with GCM

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am sending push notification to mobile using Ionic 1.x. I am getting notification, but the problem is that lengthy message is not shown completely. I have seen some link where they said to change the NotificationCompat with bigStyle(). I tried but not able to get.

Please let me know step by step for ionic, using notification plugin and in which file i have to modify.

After helping me you can mark it as duplicate or vote down. Please help me.